# How to pass in a second argument on ReactJS onSubmit function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are the codes

```
import React from "react";

var newForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (e, text) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(text);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit("react!!!")}>
                <input type="text"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
)};

module.exports = newForm;
```

What I want to achieve with this is that when I submit the form, I want the string "react!!!" to be printed out in the console and prevent the default event from taking place at the same time.

Obviously, passing in the argument to "handleSubmit" function breaks the code.

Is there anyway to pass in an argument from onSubmit event to the functions attached to this event?

Comment: `onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event, "react!!!")}`

Comment: There is no situation, where your `render` method should be aware of something that `handleSubmit` is not - either it is a prop, or a state, or a constant define anywhere else. If not, you have some code smell...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can curry the function

```
handleSubmit: text => event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(text)
}

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit('react!!!')}>
  ...
```

Equivalent ES5 code

```
handleSubmit: function(text) {
  return function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(text)
  }.bind(this)
}
```

---

Your code is weird though because you're mixing ES6 and ES5 styles. If you're using ES6 imports, you might as well use ES6 in the rest of your code

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class NewForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit (text) {
    return event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(text)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit('react!!!')}>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
    }
  }
}

export default NewForm
```

---

Or better, since your Component doesn't use any state, you can use a [Stateless Functional Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)

```
import {Component} from 'react'

const handleSubmit = text=> event=> {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(text)
}

const NewForm = props=> (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit('react!!!')}>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
)

export default NewForm
```

Comment: This is clever but suffers the same problem I outline in my answer, which is that you are creating a new function on every render, which isn't ideal for garbage collection thrashing.

Comment: John, correct me if I'm wrong, but elements aren't re-rendered unless some part of them changes. Either way, this would be a premature optimization. Unless this form was in the middle of a high-volume loop, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, elements are re-rendered any time they or any of their parents are re-rendered, which happens as a result of a change to state or props. It is possible that re-rendering can happen frequently, especially for example in forms as a result of keyboard events (depending how things are structured.) Granted, onSubmit is an event which is likely to not be called often, but event handlers are something which are used often and I think it is worthwhile to know that putting any sort of anonymous function within a render method is inefficient.

Comment: eslint now warns about this pattern as well; it is simply good practice to avoid creating new functions within render.

Comment: To be fair, in this case, it is probably fine to use an arrow function; however if you learn this is the main way to solve this problem and then apply it to another situation (say within a table where you have hundreds of cells that you can filter, for example), all of a sudden the inefficiencies can add up. As always with development it's a matter of tradeoffs. I just wanted to highlight the pros and cons of the various means to approach this particular problem.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but you shouldn't do it. What you are currently doing is saying 'set the onSubmit handler to being the result of calling this.handleSubmit('react!!!')'. What would work instead is to go:

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e, "react!!!")}>
```

which is of course just the short form of saying:

```
<form onSubmit={function(e) { this.handleSubmit(e, "react!!!"); }}>
```

However, although this will work, what this is doing is defining a new anonymous function every time render is called. Render can be called often, so this will end up with a bunch of new functions being created all the time, which can cause perf issues as they need to be garbage collected and cleaned up.

What is better is to have a function which is capable of finding the data you need on its own. There are 2 different ways which I use to address this:

- Either store the relevant data in props, so that it can be pulled out from `this.props`
- Or, store the relevant data in the DOM (using [HTML 5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)), and then pull them out using javascript. Since you are given the event target in the event handler that is called, you can use it to pull out any data attributes you have stored. For example you might declare your form like this:

  `<form data-somefield={something.interesting} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

which you could access in handleSubmit by going:

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.somefield);
}
```

The caveat there being that a) storing data in the DOM like this doesn't feel very idiomatic React, and b) if you use this for onClick events with nested elements, you might find that you have to climb up the DOM hierarchy to find where your data is stored. As an example if you have a div with a data attribute and an onClick but it contains a span and an image, when you click the image it's possible that is what the onClick handler will see as it's target element, meaning you'd have to go up to the parent to find the div with the data attribute you're looking for.

So it's probably best to just include the data you want in your component's props and pull it out from there in your event handler.

Comment: I think the recommendations in the latter of this answer go too far out of the way to avoid using simple functions; the fundamental building blocks of any good javascript program. Remember to use your profiler and only make non-idiomatic changes when performance is a proven issue.

Comment: I agree the second suggestion is the less ideal solution for the reasons I explained. I remember trying it when for example having a `<ul>` tag with a bunch of `<li>'s` which I wanted to have an onClick event which would also pass their ID along to act on. It ended up being a pain for the caveats I outlined so in the future I will likely just create a new component so that I can pass the relevant info I need through props.

Comment: That's completely different tho. In that situation you should have a single `onClick` handler on the `<ul>` and then use `event.srcElement` to reference the clicked `<li>`

Comment: Ultimately I got it working just fine, it was just more trouble than it was worth in comparison to simply creating a new Component to pass the ID through as props. It really isn't _completely_ different because we're still talking about being able to pass additional information along with an event to it's event handler.

Comment: Well you might've made it more work than you had to. Apples and oranges tho, I suppose. I made you a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about. Even tho many children act on an event, they don't need independent listeners. Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: [jsfiddle: z0ue9ss3](https://jsfiddle.net/z0ue9ss3/1/)

Comment: Well first of all, I wouldn't use a non-standard feature that is not supported in one of the major browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement), but even that's ok because it's easy enough to simply use `event.target`, however here is a fiddle which outlines why this was unreliable for my use case, which had varying levels of depth of children beneath where the desired data was stored: https://jsfiddle.net/eLyfbfjk/ . Like I said I solved it but it still ended up leaving me thinking I should have created a component instead of this approach.

Comment: John, you do pose an interesting problem. I'm going to give this one some more thought and see what turns out.

Comment: In any case I don't mean to be argumentative, thanks for the discussion :)

Comment: Likewise. I found it to be constructive ^_^